# After `yesod devel`?

Tags: web, yesod

I am new to using yesod and haskell. I just managed to create a small scaffolded site that can be run by `stack exec -- yesod devel`. But then I am confused: what should I do to get this site online?
I know this is an elementary question; probably I just don't understand how web development works: I don't know much about web development, and this might be a stupid question, but I can't find any relevant discussion in [yesod book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book).
I have looked up in some tutorial on how to get website online, and usually this means uploading some html files. But I don't see any html files generated by yesod either.
Any help or reference on this beginner's question will be well appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite detailed instructions can be found in the Yesod book: http://www.yesodweb.com/book/deploying-your-webapp

Long story short: to deploy a Yesod server you need to forward requests from a HTTP server (like Apache or Nginx) to your application (probably on Warp). By "your application" I mean executable file (compiled Haskell code), server configuration and static files (images, fonts, JS libraries ...).

And if by "online" you mean "publicly accessible", then you need to do this on a server that has a constant network connection (preferably public IP), which usually means some external hosting, for example a VPS.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now I have a quite vague impression about this. :) Though I have some more questions after reading the chapter in yesod book, I shall post new questions. :P